# Model validation logic in the database via constraints. Good idea, bad idea, or not worth it?

Tags: sql, django, database

It's always rubbed me the wrong way to write code in my model's `clean` method to validate various constraints on the data when these same constraints aren't also present in the database.

After all, the database already has constraints for *some* of my data, like NOT NULL.

So, I've been writing RawSQL migrations that `ADD CONSTRAINT some_logic` in my most recent project that matches whatever logic I have in my `clean()` method.

It works OK, but it isn't an insignificant task to remember to add these constraints, add tests for these migrations, and update them when my model changes.  Also, of course, I'm violating DRY by writing code in two places to do the same thing.

Should I give up this quixotic quest?

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means a comprehensive answer, but at least I wanted to give my opinion.

There has been many frameworks that have pushed the idea of removing the constraints from the database, in order to check them at the application level. The idea seemed nice to me at first (in the early 2000s) but after some years I came to the (very personal) conclusion that this is a bad idea.

I think, to me it boils down to two things:

- Data survives much longer than the applications. Whole systems go obsolete, but the data survives many more years. Sometimes the application is replaced, but the database is stil the same one.
- The application is not as reliable when it comes to validate data. I'm talking about programming defects here. One version of the app may work well and then the next one has a bug. It may be that one developer moves out of the company, then the new replacement -- who doesn't know as much -- changes the app with disastrous consequences. All that time a simple database constraint (that is usually very cheap to implement) could have enforced data quality.

Yep, I'm a fan of strict database constraint. Nevertheless, this doesn't mean I'm against application validations. These ones can show much nicer error messages.

Answer (score 2):

If writing too much logic in `clean()` feels dirty, an in-between solution would be to use [Django's built-in validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/) directly on your model fields.

The validation logic isn't saved in the database, but it is tracked in migrations. Like `clean()` logic, Validators require you to call `Model.clean_fields()`, but a `ModelForm` does this automatically.

You can also dig into [`django-db-constraints`](https://github.com/rapilabs/django-db-constraints). The library might help do what you're looking to do, and the source code might help you roll a solution that fits your needs.